# MVC POST to controller action and pass param from listview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, post, jquery-mobile

Im working on a project and another devloper has some code like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>       


@foreach (var product in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("SelectProduct", "Home", new {productId = product.Id}))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="submit_form" onclick="submitForm();">@product.Id</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

It builds a 2 column table with clickable products ids, and product names.
It posts to a SelectProduct action on the home controller when clicking a productId

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectProduct(Guid productId)
{
   ...
}
```

I like this because it is a POST and doesnt send the productId in the url\querystring.
(I changed the code for this example, these arnt really productIds and id prefer to not have this data in the url)

But i dont like this because...

- It doesnt work because it always posts form[0]
- Not sure i like how it creates a form for every product
- It is messing up my jquery mobile listview I am working on, the formatting is all strange. I'm not exactly sure why but think because of the forms.

In contrast i have a the following listview with anchor tags and that renders just fine.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="b">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeControllerA")">Some Controller A</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeControllerB")">Some Controller B</a> </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeControllerC")">Some Controller C</a> </li>
</ul>
```

So my questions is...

How can I make a similar table / list of products with the same functionality (i.e. click a productID and POST to a controller action passing productId but not in querystring) without using seperate repeating forms?

I was thinking maybe just 1 form, but somehow the proper productID gets passed to controller.  This way i could have the *Html.BeginForm* outside the *@foreach (var product in Model)*.

I think I'm trying to do something somewhat similar to what web forms LinkButton used to do in a grid.
It's like i want ActionLinks but i want them to POST instead of GET.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code a has a number of wrong points. I am suggesting an alternative approach using ajax

1.Using the foreach you are making a number of forms within a single page. and while submitting you are submitting the first form(`document.forms[0].submit()`). alone

rewrite Your html as follows

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{

<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="submit_form" onclick="submitForm(@product.Id);"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @product.Name
    </td>
</tr>

}
```

and make ajax call to the server using jquery.

```
var productid;
        function submitForm(productid) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/Home/SelectProduct?productId="+productid,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (_results) {
               $("#resultdiv").html(_results);
            },
            error: function (_results) {
            }
        });
    }
```

and accept the productid as a query string

```
var ProductId=HttpContext.Request.QueryString["productId"]
```

2.Still if you are following the same approach...
You are expecting the query string as a parameter in the action method. Its wrong

You can accept it like this.
(In the following snippet `using (Html.BeginForm("SelectProduct", "Home", new {productId = product.Id}))` the productId property u have added can be accepted as a query string in the server side method.)

```
var ProductId=HttpContext.Request.QueryString["productId"]
```

Comment: You can definitely get the productId as a parameter in the action method

Comment: This is not fully working for me.  If i change ajax to a POST it will hit the controller action and i can see the productId but it does not return the view (return View();) in my controller action instead it goes back to existing page as if I'm going to do something with the result of ajax call.  Maybe i don't fully understand, but I'm not looking for ajax type functionality like call server side and return to current page to update something on that page.

Comment: I have modified the answer . see   $("#resultdiv").html(_results); line. rendering the result back to the target result devision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with normal link ( with `<a>` tag).Use `Ajax.ActionLink()` method instead. [Documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

**Example:**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Click this link", "SelectProduct","Home", new { productId = product.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DivToUpdateWithResult", HttpMethod = "POST" ,OnComplete = "js_function_to_call_afterComplete();" })
```